# TURN OFF Mobile Browser Simulator in Websphere

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-rad, mobile-browser

I am running Rational Applications Developer v7 and I have an error when I start the Websphere server. It attempts to load Mobile Browser Simulator, fails to create temp file, and uses a nested strategy, which loops and then completely fails.   (The system cannot find the file specified. _MobileBrowserSimulator)

We do not need this Mobile Browser Simulator, so **is there any way to TURN IT OFF?**

> [1/6/16 8:56:28:347 EST] 00000000 wtp           E org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.impl.CommonarchiveFactoryImpl createTempZipFileStrategyIfPossible Failed to open input stream on target [ _MobileBrowserSimulator.war ].
>   Failed to create temporary file.
>   A nested strategy will be used, but this usually slows performance dramatically.
>
> [1/6/16 8:56:28:472 EST] 00000000 annotations   W AnnotativeMetadataManagerImpl scan Caught exception while scanning
>                                    org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.commonarchivecore.internal.exception.NestedJarException: IWAE0008E An error occurred reading _MobileBrowserSimulator.war from C:\Documents and Settings\username\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.ibm.etools.webtools.mobile.ui\projects_MobileBrowserSimulatorEAR\EarContent
>   Stack trace of nested exception:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Documents and Settings\username\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0_MobileBrowserSimulator (The system cannot find the file specified.)

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The mobile browser simulator is an application running on your WebSphere server.  To get rid of it, open the WebSphere admin console, go to the "Applications" section, and uninstall the _MobileBrowserSimulatorEAR application.